# Very slow speed while mounting via SSHFS

Tags: 12.04, ssh, shared-folders, sshfs, qemu

My host is ubuntu 12.04. My guest is vanilla 3.0.33 kernel with custom rootfs. I have encountered the subj problem, while mounting host folder on the guest machine via sshfs.

```
sshfs alexhoppus@10.0.2.2:/home/alexhoppus/Desktop/fold  /fold_sshfs
```

I can see all files and folders open / read / write them but again, it takes a lot of time to copy 20MB file from host to guest. I takes approximately 30 sec to copy 1000K.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

PS I saw this thread [SSHFS very slow in 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128722/sshfs-very-slow-in-12-04) but it offered solutions do not work at all.

--- Added ----

I just checked - the same thing is with NFS.

Comment: Is it maybe your connection?? (Bandwidth)

Comment: I have the same issue, with a 1G bandwidth line ...

Comment: I use sshfs and nfs mounts and neither are slow..   Sounds a network bandwidth issue rather than a protocol based on.

If you copy a large file using sftp between the two boxs what is the transfer speed?